# moment js sometimes has moment.monthsShort() with period (dot) in german locale

Tags: javascript, momentjs, simpledateformat, jira-plugin

I have written a JIRA plugin which uses moment js to format and parse dates.
On some installations I am getting a strange behaviour when moment.js has the short names with a trailing period.

Where does moment.js get the shortNames from? How do I achieve to always get the same short names?

At the moment, the parse of a date like 3/Okt/16 fails on my Ubuntu instance, but works on Mac. Where 3/Okt./16 seems to work on both.

Since the field is populated through Java SimpleDateFormat, I have no chance to change the incoming format.

Examples called from The same Browser:

```
JIRA Server hosted on MacOS:
moment.monthsShort()
["Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"]

JIRA Server hosted on Ubuntu:
moment.monthsShort()
["Jan.", "Febr.", "Mrz.", "Apr.", "Mai", "Jun.", "Jul.", "Aug.", "Sept.", "Okt.", "Nov.", "Dez."]
```

Comment: I'm positive you have two different versions of moment loading - we added the change in . parsing in 2.13 IIRC. That said, can I see your parsing code? I want to know how you are parsing. Are you getting a console warning that says moment construction falls back to js date?

Comment: That is right, i checked the versions and the failing one is 2.13.0, the working one is 2.6.0. The version, in my case, is coming from jira itself and i can't controll which will be used. The parsing is done this way: moment('3/Okt/16','D/MMM/YY');, no console outputs like you said.

Comment: I thought that the unicode conventions would be the leading source for the spec what short names are. They are all without trailing periods. But may be I'm not deep enough into that topic: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table

Comment: Yeah, we wish! Unfortunately we aren't there yet. I think I can maybe write you some code that gets around this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I think your best bet is to write some code that checks if moment is version 2.13 or greater, and overwrites with the old locale data if it is. The following code should do the trick:

```
if(moment.version.split('.')[1] > 12) 
{ 
    moment.updateLocale('de',{
    monthsShort:'Jan_Febr_Mrz_Apr_Mai_Jun_Jul_Aug_Sept_Okt_Nov_Dez'.split('_')

    });
}
moment('3/Okt/16','D/MMM/YY').format() //"2016-10-03T00:00:00-07:00"
```

Comment: Thank you Maggie, thats really kind to help out with that idea, unfortunately we have an international application rolled out and I cannot maintain that for all languages.

Comment: I think i will use the long representation of the date to hand it over to JS. Then the representation which is made by moment.js will not affekt our product.